# How to generate kubernetes yaml file using template generator?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am kubernetes newbie, and I have a basic question

my understanding from https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/ is , we can generate yaml templates using "kubernetes run" command

But when I tried doing same, it didn't work
[image: attachment]

Not sure if my understanding is wrong or something wrong in my command

Comment: Please don't include images of commands, instead copy and paste the commands themselves. Images cannot be searched.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're just missing a few flags.

The command should be

```
kubectl run <podname> --image <imagename:tag> --dry-run -o yaml --generator=run-pod/v1
```

for example:

```
kubectl run helloworld --image=helloworld --dry-run -o yaml --generator=run-pod/v1
```

Comment: 1) from documentation I guess there is no way to generate yaml for service right ? 2) and replicaset 3) wondering why we have two versions for Deployments extensions/v1beta1 & apps/v1beta1

Comment: 1. You can run something like this `kubectl create service nodeport myapp --dry-run --tcp=8080:8080 -o yaml` and that will generate the service yaml for you.
  
2. Running the same command as the pod command in my first answer but without the generator tag will create a deployment.  

3. I think that the extensions path was from when deployments were experimental.  

edit: Formatting

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify all the required flags, in this case `--image=...`